# Swift 2: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type to non-throwing function

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I have some (ugly) self-written code ported to Swift2 and got this error message in a lambda function:

[image: function with error]

What I didn't understand is, that I handle the whole code with the error throwing function JSONObjectWithData and catch the error. I throw nothing in the code. Nevertheless the compiler means that I am throwing an error.

I need to understand this behavior. Please be kind because I know that I have to improve my code to make full use of the new error handling concept in swift2.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This was fast. I have figured the solution for my problem out with a little help of this article:

http://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

you have to put a general catch clause at the end of the code because the catch of NSError alone is not sufficient.

```
catch let error as NSError
{
   failure(error: error)
   return
}

// this is important -->
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you think Apple made `catch` exhaustive with Swift 2, when we didn't even have `try` and `catch` in Swift 1/1.2?

Comment: You don't have to catch the error specifically. There should be an error reference available in the general catch block.

Comment: Hi Jon, could you give me an example, how I could use the error reference in the general catch block?. Thank you

Comment: This actually didnt help me. I still get the error " Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void'".

Comment: There is good reason as to why we need to do this: In case the error thrown *is* something other than TheErrorsYouExpected you would STILL be able to catch it. For more info see the comments for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183711/how-to-print-error-in-catch/40184140#40184140) answer. Say your errors were expected to be of type BadNetworkError, but all of sudden you got a lowMemoryError. The vanila catch would save you!

Comment: Works for Swift 3 as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way forward is to change your failure function signature to take an `ErrorType`. Then just

```
catch let error {
    failure(error: error)
}
```

will do.

Comment: When using Apple API, it may be preferable to cast the error to NSError as Apple methods tend to throw an NSError object.  Apple's NSError objects contain additional details about the error that occurred, which are accessed in NSError-specific properties such as .localizedDescription and .userInfo.  "JSONObjectWithData" from the original poster's comment throws an NSError object.  CoreData methods also will throw NSError objects.  I prefer casting the error to NSError from INSIDE the catch block so that the catch is exhaustive.