# Swift 2 - CoreData - NSManagedObjectContext Cannot invoke 'save' with an argument list of type '(inout NSError?)'

Tags: ios, core-data, uiwebview

I am trying to follow this **[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift)** in order to save the Local Cache of UIWebView in my app.

I had to convert a few lines to swift 2 but i cannot find the way to solve the issue when add to NSManagedObjectContext save an argument of type NSError.

from the picture you can understand better what I mean.

[image]

How could I fix this?
The code I'm using is:

```
func saveCachedResponse () {
    print("Saving cached response")

    // 1
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.managedObjectContext!

    // 2
    let cachedResponse = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CachedURLResponse", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    cachedResponse.setValue(self.mutableData, forKey: "data")
    cachedResponse.setValue(self.request.URL!.absoluteString, forKey: "url")
    cachedResponse.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timestamp")
    cachedResponse.setValue(self.response.MIMEType, forKey: "mimeType")
    cachedResponse.setValue(self.response.textEncodingName, forKey: "encoding")

    // 3
    var error: NSError?
    let success = context.save(&error)
    if !success {
        print("Could not cache the response")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Surface Error**

Handle `print("Could not cache the response")` not listed in the other answers:

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch let error {
    print("Could not cache the response \(error)")
}
```

**Avoid DB corruption, use perform block for all MOC access**

As I like code examples to be somewhat robust, here is a more exhaustive solution:

```
func saveCachedResponse (context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    context.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in

        let cachedResponse = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CachedURLResponse", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        cachedResponse.setValue(self.mutableData, forKey: "data")
        // etc.

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not cache the response \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: how do you rethrow the error to the caller of saveCachedResponse? I get "invalid conversion from throwing to non-throwing" on the save() line.

Comment: While I could answer this here, comments are not to ask question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826560/swift-2-invalid-conversion-from-throwing-function-of-type-to-non-throwing-funct, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443645/simplest-way-to-throw-an-error-exception-with-a-custom-message-in-swift-2.

Answer (score 3):

### In Swift 2.0

To save context, you have to use `do { try ...}` and `catch {...}` your error.

```
// Save the context.
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

### Edit

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CachedURLResponse", inManagedObjectContext: context)
let newCacheUrl = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context)

newCacheUrl.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")
```

I use something like this with Xcode 7 and I have not `fatal error`.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, I have changed to do { try ...} however, I get the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: **Try :** let context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext

Comment: Thank you Antonio, still have the same issue.. However, I solved it to compile my project with Xcode 6.4... Seems that Xcode 7 beta is not ready yet

Comment: I post an edit in my answer to try to solve your error.

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError
{
    NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer a little bit

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    let success = try context.save()
} catch {

}
```

will do the trick. The error got nothing to do Xcode 7.