# how to print error in catch

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums, try-catch

```
catch let error as LocksmithError{
print(error)// it would print the case of the error.
}
```

However if I do

```
catch LocksmithError.Duplicate{

}

catch{
print (LocksmithError) // Obviously I would just print LocksmithError, it won't print the case
print (LocksmithError.rawValue) // prints nothing
}
```

**My question is:** Using the 2nd approach is there any that I can actually retrieve and the value/case of the error? Or if I don't get the value right at the entry point ie the catch, then I miss the chance of doing it!

Comment: You can `print(error)` in the unconditional `catch`.

Comment: @Hamish I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You can write `catch { print(error) }`...

Comment: @Hamish but say if it was case *Duplicate* as here and I have **already** catched that, then I won't be able to print it

Comment: Yes, that's how catching works. Did I misunderstand your question? I thought you were just asking how you could retrieve the error in the final `catch` block. So your question is really how to print a given error regardless if it's already been caught or not? If so, please [edit] your post to make this clear :)

Comment: @Hamish **I** didn't explain well. So I just tried, Unexpectedly I *can* print error in the unconditional catch, but if I try to print/log it inside the .Duplicate catch, then I still get **Unresolved identifier 'error'**. I'm curious why in one the error exists but in the other doesn't and what's the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `catch` blocks are exclusive cases, evaluated in order. When a match succeeds, we *stop*.

So, let's just think about this structure:

```
catch LocksmithError.Duplicate {
    // 1
    print("duplicate")
}
catch {
    // 2
    print(error)
}
```

If we are at **1**, then what is in scope is the `LocksmithError.Duplicate`.

If we are at **2**, then what is in scope is every *other* kind of error that gets caught. There's no way you can get hold of the `LocksmithError.Duplicate` here, because *ex hypothesi* it would have been caught in **1** and we wouldn't *be* here.

Now, the way *I* would do it is like this:

```
catch let err as LocksmithError {
    // 1
    print(err)
}
catch {
    // 2
    print(error)
}
```

That may be the sort of thing you are after; it gives us a value `err` that carries the error into the curly braces in **1**. (The automatic `error` value exists only the final catch-all `catch` block.)

Comment: It seems that I haven't explained well. I want to be able to print(error) in 1 & 2. In 1 it would print 'duplicate' in 2 it would print whatever the error is

Comment: Then in 1 just write `print("duplicate")`. You know you are right because if it were not Locksmith.Duplicate we wouldn't be here.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: As usual, I recommend reading my book on this topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_throwing_and_catching_errors

Comment: WuW! So the difference of `err` & `error` is that `err` is catching whatever you were expecting to crash, but `error` is catching *whatever* else

Comment: You're overthinking this. `err` is just a name I made up. I could have called it `wibblyWobblyWoo`.

Comment: @matt. That much I know :) What I did learn was that you 1) get access to local error, inside unconditioned catches 2) you must always have a default catch for even error types you didn't expect 3) And you can never access the error inside a catch. You can only manually print a message...

Comment: "you can never access the error inside a catch" No, my code _does_ access the error inside the catch. Inside _both_ catches. In fact, the only time you _can't_ access the error inside the catch is when there is no need to do so, i.e. your catch pattern completely determines the identity of the error.